# Javascript: Send Array of ints through node.js binary websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, websocket

I have the following case. I capture a webcam frame via a canvas with `context.getImageData().data`. That gives me a nice Array (or UInt8ClampedArray says Bidelman) of ints like `[r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a, etc.]` when I `console.log()` them. Now I want to send this to a node.js server via binaryjs and of course the data get's scrambled like hell: https://gist.github.com/thgie/6550638

How can I convert the Array to something binary first or how do I get the binary back to a readable array?

**Code examples**

Client:

```
client.send(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT).data, {'id': 'bin', 'frame': frame});
```

Server:

```
client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){

  var bufs = [];

  stream.on('data', function(data){
    bufs.push(data);
  });

  stream.on('end', function(){

    var buf = Buffer.concat(bufs);

    fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/tmp/"+meta.frame+".dat", buf, "binary", function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

It will look like this:

```
H>DÿNDJÿL@FÿPCJÿR@KÿQ?IÿLDPÿKCOÿMCKÿLAIÿL@DÿL@DÿLBGÿKAFÿIAHÿLDLÿLAIÿLAIÿO@IÿO@IÿIAJÿJBKÿMCIÿNDJÿQEIÿQEIÿPGHÿOFGÿMIHÿMIHÿPDFÿNCEÿIBDÿLEHÿPDFÿPDFÿMHLÿLGKÿMHLÿNIMÿOGLÿNFKÿOEMÿPFNÿRFSÿPERÿPERÿPERÿRGOÿSHPÿSGMÿSGMÿRJRÿQIPÿQJNÿRKPÿRKPÿQJNÿSGMÿSGMÿOHJÿSLOÿQJLÿRKMÿSIJÿTKKÿQLPÿPJNÿSLQÿRKPÿSLQÿUMRÿSKSÿUMTÿVMWÿSKUÿUJUÿRGQÿUMTÿUMTÿSKUÿVMWÿSMTÿSMTÿQNVÿQNVÿSMVÿTNWÿZMVÿXKTÿUJUÿVKVÿTOSÿTOSÿWQUÿWQUÿYTVÿYTVÿXRVÿUPTÿYSZÿYSZÿXRVÿZUYÿWPRÿYRTÿWRQÿXSRÿVOOÿWPPÿXRVÿXRVÿZOYÿ[P[ÿZO[ÿ\Q^ÿZT_ÿZT_ÿZV`ÿZV`ÿ]T^ÿ]T^ÿ^TZÿ`V[ÿ[VXÿ[VXÿ]UZÿ^V[ÿZV`ÿ[Waÿ_Xdÿ_Xdÿ]X`ÿ]X`ÿaZ_ÿaZ_ÿ_Y]ÿ`[_ÿ`Y]
```

Comment: If you are using binaryjs then it does it for you. Make sure you use binaryjs on server and client sides to communicate, and it will handle compressing and decompressing for you.

Comment: Then I do something wrong with the buffer. Because doesn't matter how I convert it, I just get scrambled traces.

Comment: The `buf` argument you're passing to `fs.writeFile` is an actual Buffer, right? Something is stringifying your data, apparently.

Comment: I'm very sure it's a buffer. From the docs of binaryjs: On Node.js, binary data is received as Buffer. But I don't send binary data. I send an array and I'm somehow not convinced binaryjs solves that for me. Maybe if I send an ArrayBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the browser side, you can verify easily enough using chrome's dev tools.  Look at the binary traffic and it will tell you if your sending binary of text frames.  They are different kinds of frames in the websocket spec.

On the node side, you can verify your buffer values are truly node buffers by using `Buffer.isBuffer()`.  I see you're writing your buffer using the "binary" string encoding.  This is probably not what you want.  In node, the encoding for native `Buffer` instances is `null`.  The `"binary"`, `"ascii"`, `"utf8"`, `"hex"`, `"base64"` encodings are all string encodings/decodings.  What the binary encoding means is that every byte is stored in the string as a 8-bit unicode code point.

```
// Convert a binary buffer into a "binary" encoded string.
function binaryEncode(buffer) {
  var string = "";
  for (var i = 0, l = buffer.length; i < l; i++) {
    string += String.fromCharCode(buffer[i]);
  }
  return string
}

// Convert a "binary" encoded string into a binary buffer.
function binaryDecode(string) {
  var length = string.length;
  var buffer = new Buffer(length);
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    buffer[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
}
```

Storing binary data can thus be done quite safely in JavaScript strings (which are defined as having 16 bit unicode code points per character).  It's not the most efficient thing since you're wasting the upper 8 bits of every character and this is why node.js prefers native Buffers.  But in things like browser crypto libraries, this "binary" string encoding is common since it is supported on all JS platforms.